# Quickblox User limit for private group

Tags: quickblox

I have questions on quickblox
a.) Whats the user limit for private group
b.) For public group is pushnotification supported?

Answer (score 1):

There is no any limits of users count for private group chats

For public group chat the Push Notification are not supported because there is no any members list here

Comment: So I tried implemeting quickblox in my project. And to recieve a notification  of incomming message I signed in the user to every public group which was there in the dialog list which is inefficient. Is there a way to implement a message listener for any incoming chats so that the user doesnt have to be signed in to all the dialogs to get an update?

Comment: The right way for now is to join every group chat after login